# Show all options in tokenize2

Tags: tokenize2

I am using tokenize2 library for multiselection. It works fine for me but I want to show all items in dropdown on click. Is it possible in tokenize2? 
please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Change the following style on your tokenize2.css file. It works for me.

```
.tokenize-dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
 min-height: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: -1px 0 0 0;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 max-height: 200px !important;
 overflow: auto; }
```

And change on tokenize2.js file the following

```
if($('li.dropdown-item', this.dropdown).length <= this.options.dropdownMaxItems){
```

to

```
if ($('li.dropdown-item', this.dropdown).length <= items.length) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party but this worked for me.

```
$('Selector').on('tokenize:select', function(container) {
    $(this).tokenize2().trigger('tokenize:search', [$(this).tokenize2().input.val()]);
});
```